# BeginCollectionItem not binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding, mvc-editor-templates

I've previously used the Html.BeginCollectionItem() extension and had no issues with binding from view to controller. In my current project however I'm having issues.

The model

```
    public class EditPathViewModel : TradeContractorEscalationPath
    {
         public Guid ContractorId { get; set; }
         public List<ContactDisplayModel> Contacts { get; set; }
         public List<TradeContractorEscalationPathContact> AssignedContacts { get; set; }
         public int maxOrder { get; set; }
    }

   public partial class TradeContractorEscalationPath
   {        
       public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
       public System.Guid TradeContractorId { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
       public string Notes { get; set; }
       public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
       public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }        
   }
```

I am trying to bind AssignedContacts back to the Controller, which looks like...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EditPath([Bind(Include = "Id,TradeContractorId,Description,Notes,ContractorId,AssignedContacts,Contacts")] Models.EditPathViewModel model)
    {
        ...
    }
```

However, it constantly returns null. The BeginCollectionItem is configured like so:

**Editor Template for TradeContractorEscalationPathContact**

```
@model Telecare.POCO.TradeContractorEscalationPathContact

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Order)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TradeContractorEscalationPathId)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactId)
```

**The view where Assigned Contacts collection item is called**

```
    ...
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="ibox-title">
            <h5>Contacts</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssignedContacts)
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
```

**Example HTML from DOM when POST is called**

```
...
   <input name="AssignedContacts.index" class="ui-sortable-handle" type="hidden" value="a5895b40-2de5-4ed5-a3ed-137c047963e8" autocomplete="off">
   <input name="AssignedContacts[a5895b40-2de5-4ed5-a3ed-137c047963e8].Order" class="text-box single-line ui-sortable-handle" id="AssignedContacts_a5895b40-2de5-4ed5-a3ed-137c047963e8__Order" type="number" value="1" data-val-required="The Order field is required." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Order must be a number.">
   <input name="AssignedContacts[a5895b40-2de5-4ed5-a3ed-137c047963e8].TradeContractorEscalationPathId" class="text-box single-line ui-sortable-handle" id="AssignedContacts_a5895b40-2de5-4ed5-a3ed-137c047963e8__TradeContractorEscalationPathId" type="text" value="0807186a-3bad-e811-9c42-8cae4cf36195" data-val-required="The Trade Contractor Path field is required." data-val="true">
   <input name="AssignedContacts[a5895b40-2de5-4ed5-a3ed-137c047963e8].ContactId" class="text-box single-line ui-sortable-handle" id="AssignedContacts_a5895b40-2de5-4ed5-a3ed-137c047963e8__ContactId" type="text" value="1e09c3ae-42ac-e811-9c42-8cae4cf36195" data-val-required="The Contact field is required." data-val="true">
   <input name="AssignedContacts.index" class="ui-sortable-handle" type="hidden" value="974a0c38-642b-40f1-a5bd-dbc4b880eaa2" autocomplete="off">
   <input name="AssignedContacts[974a0c38-642b-40f1-a5bd-dbc4b880eaa2].Order" class="text-box single-line ui-sortable-handle" id="AssignedContacts_974a0c38-642b-40f1-a5bd-dbc4b880eaa2__Order" type="number" value="2" data-val-required="The Order field is required." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Order must be a number.">
   <input name="AssignedContacts[974a0c38-642b-40f1-a5bd-dbc4b880eaa2].TradeContractorEscalationPathId" class="text-box single-line ui-sortable-handle" id="AssignedContacts_974a0c38-642b-40f1-a5bd-dbc4b880eaa2__TradeContractorEscalationPathId" type="text" value="0807186a-3bad-e811-9c42-8cae4cf36195" data-val-required="The Trade Contractor Path field is required." data-val="true">
   <input name="AssignedContacts[974a0c38-642b-40f1-a5bd-dbc4b880eaa2].ContactId" class="text-box single-line ui-sortable-handle" id="AssignedContacts_974a0c38-642b-40f1-a5bd-dbc4b880eaa2__ContactId" type="text" value="f9d8afdd-42ac-e811-9c42-8cae4cf36195" data-val-required="The Contact field is required." data-val="true">
   <input name="AssignedContacts.index" type="hidden" value="75a5e8e5-82e1-4f58-b185-ca6abefc5d9c" autocomplete="off">
   <input name="AssignedContacts[75a5e8e5-82e1-4f58-b185-ca6abefc5d9c].Order" class="text-box single-line" id="AssignedContacts_75a5e8e5-82e1-4f58-b185-ca6abefc5d9c__Order" type="number" value="3" data-val-required="The Order field is required." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Order must be a number.">
   <input name="AssignedContacts[75a5e8e5-82e1-4f58-b185-ca6abefc5d9c].TradeContractorEscalationPathId" class="text-box single-line" id="AssignedContacts_75a5e8e5-82e1-4f58-b185-ca6abefc5d9c__TradeContractorEscalationPathId" type="text" value="0807186a-3bad-e811-9c42-8cae4cf36195" data-val-required="The Trade Contractor Path field is required." data-val="true">
   <input name="AssignedContacts[75a5e8e5-82e1-4f58-b185-ca6abefc5d9c].ContactId" class="text-box single-line" id="AssignedContacts_75a5e8e5-82e1-4f58-b185-ca6abefc5d9c__ContactId" type="text" value="9ea0dcf8-42ac-e811-9c42-8cae4cf36195" data-val-required="The Contact field is required." data-val="true">
   <input name="AssignedContacts.index" type="hidden" value="965b81be-f52c-4055-8b4b-bccf916f14a4" autocomplete="off">
   <input name="AssignedContacts[965b81be-f52c-4055-8b4b-bccf916f14a4].Order" class="text-box single-line" id="AssignedContacts_965b81be-f52c-4055-8b4b-bccf916f14a4__Order" type="number" value="4" data-val-required="The Order field is required." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Order must be a number.">
   <input name="AssignedContacts[965b81be-f52c-4055-8b4b-bccf916f14a4].TradeContractorEscalationPathId" class="text-box single-line" id="AssignedContacts_965b81be-f52c-4055-8b4b-bccf916f14a4__TradeContractorEscalationPathId" type="text" value="0807186a-3bad-e811-9c42-8cae4cf36195" data-val-required="The Trade Contractor Path field is required." data-val="true">
   <input name="AssignedContacts[965b81be-f52c-4055-8b4b-bccf916f14a4].ContactId" class="text-box single-line" id="AssignedContacts_965b81be-f52c-4055-8b4b-bccf916f14a4__ContactId" type="text" value="fc7a9669-43ac-e811-9c42-8cae4cf36195" data-val-required="The Contact field is required." data-val="true">
...
```

From all the threads I've read - the HTML looks like it should correctly bind so I must be missing something or doing something wrong elsewhere? Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - turns out I'm an idiot. The code above does indeed work but it wasn't binding because it wasn't within the @Html.BeginForm()) section. Sigh.